# SUMIF a range of amounts based on a particular month and year

Tags: excel, vba

How do i sum up a range of amounts after checking through the month and year?

As you can see in the image, my code currently sums up all amounts by checking only on the month. This is incorrect as it should check the year as well before auto summing itself into the respective months and year. 
[image: Image of original summing based on MONTH only]

Here is the Excel `Cell` code:

```
Cell C36="$"&SUMIF(B17:B23,"*."&TEXT(B30,"mm")&".*",E17:E23)-SUMIF(B17:B23,"*."&TEXT(B30,"mm")&".*",G17:G23)
```

I tried modifying the code to add in a "yy" as shown below, but it didnt work out. In fact the 2017 amount of $555 reflected in 2018 instead.

```
="$"&SUMIF(B17:B23,"*."&TEXT(B30,"mm")&"."&TEXT(B30,"yy")&"",E17:E23)-SUMIF(B17:B23,"*."&TEXT(B30,"mm")&".*",G17:G23)
```

[image: Image of original summing after trying to add "yy"]

What do I need to change?

BTW, Cells B30 and B36 are Custom formatted to "mmm-yy" while Cells B17 and B18 is Text.

Comment: shouldn't you have the "yy" part in the second sumif as well?

Comment: Yup i will, but first i want to solve the Debit side first. When the Debit works, the credit is just a Copy-Paste-change-cells away.

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve my own code.

Apparently its just a change in the parameters.

```
Cell C36="$"&SUMIF(B17:B23,"*."&TEXT(B30,"mm.yy")&"*",E17:E23)-SUMIF(B17:B23,"*."&TEXT(B30,"mm.yy")&"*",G17:G23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative. SUMPRODUCT allows you to use RIGHT function to do the comparison for mm.yy.

```
="$" & SUMPRODUCT((--(RIGHT(B17:B23,5)=TEXT(B36,"mm.yy")))*E17:E23)-SUMPRODUCT((--(RIGHT(B17:B23,5)=TEXT(B36,"mm.yy")))*G17:G23)
```